# OpenGL VBO only being uploaded to GPU when rendered

Tags: c, opengl, vbo

My VBOs are only being sent to the GPU when they are used for the first time, this causes small freezes the first time an object/group of objects is drawn.

I tried loading the data this way:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, data);
```

and this way

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

But the result is the same.

If I then draw a triangle after glBufferData:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

then the problem is solved, but I find this solution rather hackish.

Is there a better solution?

(I have a bunch of small VBOs containing 256 vertices each)

Comment: Passing `NULL` to `glBufferData` means "don't copy any data".  I don't know why you would expect your two different attempts to have different results.

Comment: I wasn't expecting anything different, I just tried it because it is what they do here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Comment: @Jonathan: I swear, one of these days I'm going to wipe that Wiki article off the Internet. The correct place to find info on buffer objects is [this wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object).

Comment: "I have a bunch of small VBOs containing 256 vertices each" Stop doing that. You should try to avoid tiny buffer objects like that. Group those objects together into larger buffers.

Comment: @NicolBolas the way I structure my rendering, I have to call glBindBuffer for each of those small VBOs anyways. Having them all in separate VBOs allows me to use unsigned bytes for the indices. Taking that into consideration, should they still be grouped together?

Comment: @Jonathan: Then structure your renderer differently. There's no reason you can't use unsigned bytes for indices while still merging buffers. Just pass a non-zero offset to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: Somehow I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how Buffer Objects are supposed to work, namely adding somewhat asynchronous operation. The idea is, that you can upload a large bunch of Buffer Objects, and continue OpenGL operations afterwards, with the pipline stalling only, if data is accessed which upload has not been completed yet. glBufferData and glBufferSubData either make the pages of the pointer passed them CoW or make an interim copy, either way you can safely discard the data in your process after the call returned, the OpenGL client side will still have the data around for (the ongoing) upload process.

Calling glFinish() will block until the operations pipline has been completely finished (hence the name).

Comment: The problem is the upload is not "ongoing". The upload only happens when the VBO is used.

Comment: @Jonathan: How did you measure this? Could you post your code somewhere, and the specs of your system, so that we can reproduce?

Comment: I get a 1 second freeze the first time I render my scene, even if it has been many minutes since I loaded the VBOs (and this goes away if I draw a triangle from the VBO right after loading it). I have a Radeon HD 4870 .

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, OpenGL has many liberties about when it actually copies the data over to the server. OpenGL is defined in terms of an abstract machine. So it's perfectly valid to defer uploading the data to GPU memory until it's actually accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling glFlush() after your glBufferData call.